# powershell Get-Counter -Counter '\Process(iexplore)\Working Set - Private' not working when used in back tick

Tags: powershell

When i run this code

`powershell Get-Counter -Counter '\Process(iexplore)\Working Set - Private'`

inside the backtick it throws

> Error: "Get-Counter : The specified counter path could not be
>   interpreted.\nAt line:1 char:2\n+ & <<<<  Get-Counter -counter
>   'Process(*)Working Set - Private'\n    + CategoryInfo          : 
>   InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception\n    +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand\n \n""

Kindly help me on this.

When i run the same directly in command prompt it works fine.

Comment: I don't see any backticks. plus it works both in the console/ISE and in scripts for me

Comment: I was trying to run this in ruby inside `powershell Get-Counter -Counter '\Process(iexplore)\Working Set - Private'` and it throws error as i mentioned. But it works fine when i run it in ise.

Comment: This issues is resolved. i used \\ instead single \.